# How can I verify if a file exist inside container docker?

Tags: php, bash, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I can copy it with this code:

```
exec('docker cp selenium:"/home/seluser/Downloads/'.$fileName.'" '.$filePath.'.pdf');
```

but I need verify before if it exist

Comment: Can't you run `file_exists`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php, on `'/home/seluser/Downloads/'.$fileName`? (Depending on where those variable values come from this also may be open to shell injections)

Comment: You may find it easier (and substantially safer) to mount a volume when you start the container, rather than try to use `docker cp`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use: `exec(ls <your file> > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo 0 || echo 1)` which will output 1 if the file `<your file>` does not exist check the output or replace `echo 0` with the command to execute in case the file exist

Comment: Will this check for a file in the docker container?